# How do I install drivers for a Canon LBP-2900 printer?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I seen many times how people describe how to's about LBP-2900, and 10-12 steps from start to end of how to download, unpack, build driver, fix driver, make it work... Could be there some .deb package with ready-to-go driver for Ubuntu? This printer is very popular...

Comment: See also: [How to make LBP-1120 Canon printer work?](http://askubuntu.com/a/106260)

Comment: See also: [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04/464334?noredirect=1#comment639466_464334)

Answer (score 3):

For the printer, there is a script that should help you do this with little effort - [my source is here](http://radu.cotescu.com/2010/03/20/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/Blockquote).

You need to download the script from [the Canon Website](http://codebin.cotescu.com/canon/lbp_driver/CanonCAPTdriver.tar.gz) (you will need to extract this archive). Running the script from a terminal is easy: `sudo ./canonLBP_install.sh LBP2900`

Answer (score 2):

What did you do so far?

Setting up a LBP-Printer recently, I had to replug the USB after installing, and to restart ccpd.

Configure your printer in the browser: http://localhost:631/admin

Then, in a Shell, do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status 
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

Answer (score 1):

### For 11.10

I installed a Canon-LBP- printer on my sisters Ubuntu machine. It was a hard riddle, involving several downloads, unplugging and replugging the USB, and finally it printed, but refused to print after reboot.

There are two daemons to be started in /etc/init.d which were installed to automatically start, but sometimes, one of them, failed.

Do a

```
ps -c ccpd
```

to check, whether ccpd was started and is running, and if not

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
```

If it is running,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

which should show two port numbers. Afaik, I had to restart ccpd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
```

to bring the printer back. In /var/log/cups/error_log you could find more informations about errors. The first character means:

- d debug
- i information
- w warning
- e error

with increasing severity to the bottom. Maybe you have to activate logging and increase the loglevel (direction up) to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

### For 13.10

1. Clean install the Ubuntu 13.10
2. Download the drivers from the following link

   http://www.ssldirectory.com/downloads/files/drivers/canon/lbpxxxx/raducotescu-CanonCAPTdriver-2401-updated%20by%20unixmen-.tar.gz

   (Remember that there are many other scrips also from radu (other versions) and other writers, which I have tried but none of that worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10)
3. Extract the files
4. Follow the instruction in readme file or

   Open terminal, CD to the folder where files are extracted
   run the command

   ```
   $sudo ./canonLBP_install.sh LBP2900
   ```

   (Replace the printer number of your printer LBPXXXX)
5. Open System Settings -> Printer -> set “LBP2900” printer as Default
6. Restart PC

Resources:

- Radu Cotescu for great Script http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/
- Unixmen
- Raqa.net

Comment: I Done but it didn't work. It returned an error as same as [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/394620/152405).

Comment: There have been some effort for an out-of-the-box script here : https://github.com/dkavraal/CanonCAPTdriver (CAPT 2.60)