# How do I install drivers for a Canon LBP 2900B printer?

Tags: printing, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install drivers for a Canon LBP-2900 printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6107/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-a-canon-lbp-2900-printer)

Please help me with installation of canon LBP 2900B on my ubuntu 11.10.

I don't have programming knowledge. Please guide me step by step.