# Canon LBP3100B Printer => CAPT driver is installed => when I try to start ccpd, I get this: `Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf`

Tags: printing, canon

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Driver: CAPT v2.60 -> debian package 64 bit

Printer: LBP3100B

---

Regarding [this "Answer"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105891/how-to-make-lbp-1120-canon-printer-work/106260#106260), I've installed the canon CAPT driver on my machine, but when I try to start/restart ccpd, I get this error:

[image: chec the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf]

However, the printer doesn't work unless I start ccpd. Here is the content of `/etc/ccpd.conf`:

```
# Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS Configuration Data
<Path>
# CUPS configuration file path.
#  Default  /etc/cups/
CUPS_ConfigPath   /etc/cups/
# Log directory path.
#  LogDirectoryPath /var/log/CCPD/
</Path>
# Printer entries.
#  Mapping each "Printer Name" to each "Printer Device Port".
#  The "Printer Name" has to be identical to the CUPS printer queue name.
#  For example, if you prepare a printer named "LBP3200" as a CUPS printer
#  queue name, and the printer is connected to the USB port "/dev/usb/lp0",
#  you can use the following three lines example just by removing the
#  comment symbol "#" of each line.
#<Printer  LBP3200>
#DevicePath  /dev/usb/lp0
#</Printer>
<Printer LBP3100B>
DevicePath /dev/usb/lp0
</Printer>
<Ports>
# Status monitoring socket port.
#  Default 59787
UI_Port  59787
PDATA_Port  59687
</Ports>
```

After un-commenting `LogDirectoryPath /var/log/CCPD/` and trying to print a page, It seems the log file is not created:

```
$ ls /var/log/CCPD/
ls: cannot access /var/log/CCPD/: No such file or directory
```

The below picture is captured from the printer properties dialogue:

[image: LBP3100B on localhost]

And here is `/var/log/cups/error_log.3.gz`:

```
W [20/Dec/2013:20:54:08 +0330] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LBP3100B-Gray..' already exists
W [20/Dec/2013:20:55:35 +0330] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LBP3100B-Gray..' already exists
E [20/Dec/2013:20:59:55 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [20/Dec/2013:20:59:55 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [20/Dec/2013:20:59:55 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [20/Dec/2013:21:04:57 +0330] [Job 2] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [20/Dec/2013:21:04:57 +0330] [Job 3] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [20/Dec/2013:21:06:08 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [20/Dec/2013:21:06:08 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [20/Dec/2013:21:06:08 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [20/Dec/2013:21:06:08 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:06:45 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [21/Dec/2013:01:06:45 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:06:45 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [21/Dec/2013:01:06:45 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:11:46 +0330] [Job 2] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:11:46 +0330] [Job 3] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:12:57 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [21/Dec/2013:01:12:57 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:12:57 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [21/Dec/2013:01:12:57 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:17:58 +0330] [Job 2] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:17:58 +0330] [Job 3] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:19:09 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [21/Dec/2013:01:19:09 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:19:09 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [21/Dec/2013:01:19:09 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:24:10 +0330] [Job 2] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:24:10 +0330] [Job 3] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:25:21 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [21/Dec/2013:01:25:21 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:25:21 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [21/Dec/2013:01:25:21 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:30:22 +0330] [Job 2] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:30:22 +0330] [Job 3] Stopping unresponsive job.
E [21/Dec/2013:01:31:33 +0330] [Job 2] Can't connect to CCPD: Connection refused
E [21/Dec/2013:01:31:33 +0330] [Job 2] ccp send_data error, exit
E [21/Dec/2013:01:31:33 +0330] [Job 3] Invalid printer command "Clean".
E [21/Dec/2013:01:31:33 +0330] [Job 3] ccp send_data error, exit
```

AND

`ls /var/log`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6669726

Comment: do `/dev/usb/lp0` exist?

Comment: @Braiam, Yes; it exists.

Comment: Is not creating the log... what the `/var/log/cups` say? edit your question.

Comment: `ls /var/log/cups`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6670495/; (Question edited, check last lines, please)

Comment: Can you check the permissions for /dev/usb/lp0?  Are you in the listed group?

Comment: `ls /dev/usb/lp0` => ls: cannot access /dev/usb/lp0: No such file or directory ; Another point: This CAPT-driver perfectly works on a i686 machin, but the 64bit debian packges does not work while it's installed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HkMBJ.png

Comment: [This instruction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Canon_LBP2900) says: `Additional requirements on Arch64: lib32-libcups lib32-heimdal lib32-libxml2 lib32-popt`. should I install 32bit packages on my 64 bit machine? If yes, what are the right packages for Ubuntu?