# Install Canon 2900 driver in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I want to install a Canon 2900 printer driver in Ubuntu 16.04.

Please show screen shots of the full procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driver Canon LBP 2900](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457774/driver-canon-lbp-2900) and [How do I install drivers for a Canon LBP-2900 printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6107/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-a-canon-lbp-2900-printer)

Answer (score 3):

you need the CAPT driver from here [CAPT Printer Driver for Linux | Canon](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html) and click to download and SAVE and you will get linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz

open a terminal and copy the commands below line by line and PASTE into the terminal

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf  linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz
cd  linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian
sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
```

then `sudo service cups restart`

then to register the printer `sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E`

then to register with ccpd daemon `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0`

then restart ccpd with `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

...... and it should print

You must use the final command each time you turn the computer on; unless you set up the command to start automatically ...........

and this all assumes you have only ONE usb printer so it gets called lp0

Comment: lpadmin: Unknown argument "–E"

Comment: seems that "Turns out that the character in Canons docs before the E is not a hyphon "-". Replacing it with the legal hyphon character fixed this error." so I have done that in my answer above: try changing the character before the E to a standard hyphen

Comment: I have edited the registration section; Canon use a symbol that is not a minus sign; so I have edited and corrected this: hence the command of quangkid

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04 I'm getting the warning `lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.` after the "register the printer" command. Is this expected or did I go wrong somewhere?